# Flutter Location Import Errors

Tags: flutter, geolocation, location, flutter-dependencies

I am trying to use the Location plugin (https://pub.dev/packages/location#-readme-tab-)

I have included all dependencies in the analysis and tried to test using the example however, the following imports are throwing errors "Target of URI doesn't exist..."

```
import 'get_location.dart';
import 'listen_location.dart';
import 'permission_status.dart';
import 'service_enabled.dart';
```

I tried to import dependencies and changed my settings.gradle with no success. Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Comment: run `flutter clean` and then run `flutter pub get` also check if there are any indentation errors in `pubspec.yaml`. `pubspec.yaml` is dependent on indentation and spaces